# How to clear all tables selected through a INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES query in SQL?

Tags: sql, select, sql-delete, information-schema

The result is a list of a few hundred tables that have useless rows that should be cleared. How can I do so without manually typing each one?

Not trying to delete *all* tables, just the ones that been selected through WHERE AND

Comment: in a select you can concatenate strings. build up your delete/truncate statement concatenating the table names with the correct command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SQL_String NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TableName  NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    -- You might want to modify this in order to get only 
    -- a specific subset of tables
    SELECT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
OPEN db_cursor   

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor 
INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 

    SET @SQL_String = N'DELETE * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL_STRING

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor 
    INTO @TableName        
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Something like this should do the trick.

As always, when deleting records in tables without a `WHERE` clause, be very careful.

Comment: just copied "select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA='swag' and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%Type' and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%Code' and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%Descriptor' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'" below your comments and tried to run it, but it says
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns.

Comment: Instead of "SELECT * [...]", simply use "SELECT TABLE_NAME [...]". Since  the cursor only needs the Table Name here.

Comment: I've got it to work, but the constraints cause it to terminate before it is finished. Is there any way I can just skip the tables with constraints and go to the next table?

Comment: You'd have to drop the constraints dynamically.