# Delete from multiple tabes where table names are in array

Tags: mysql

** Tile maybe incorrect**

Without listing by hand the table names, could I use a function to get the tables names then use that in the delete statement? ie

```sql
DELETE FROM IN (
  SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE';
) AS T
WHERE
  T.ColumnName = 'value';
```

Is there a nice and clear way to do this? I'm not dropping any tables here.

Comment: No, that's not possible as easy as you envision. You'd need dynamic SQL for that, i.e. some code that generates and executes multiple `DELETE` statements.

Comment: Hi. Is it something like this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272326/how-to-clear-all-tables-selected-through-a-information-schema-tables-query-in-sq

Comment: In general yes, but the other question seems to be about SQL Server not MySQL. But the logic would be equivalent, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Ross Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12718767/3581788), I've made an addition to the table name look up.

```sql
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists hunt //
create procedure hunt()
begin
    DECLARE done BOOL default false;
    DECLARE tablename CHAR(255);
    
    -- This was the only bit I've added
    DECLARE cur1 cursor for (
        SELECT TABLE_NAME
            FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
                WHERE 
                    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' 
                AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
    );
    -- End what I've added

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;

    myloop: loop
        fetch cur1 into tablename;
        if done then
            leave myloop;
        end if;
        -- Then my delete query
        set @sql = CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', tablename, ' WHERE 'column_name' = 'value'');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        drop prepare stmt;
    end loop;

    close cur1;
end //

delimiter ;

call hunt();
```